# understanding functions and numbers

Tags: javascript, math

```
var a = 3;
var b = 5;
example(a, b);

function example(b, a) {
  var result = b - a;
  alert(result);
}
```

My question is looking at this I though the result would be 2 but its negative 2 can someone explain why please?

Answer (score 1):

You've inverted the arguments in your function definition.

While you are calling `(a,b)`, you are receiving `(b,a)`.  This means that you are passing:

```
 example(3,5)
```

and receiving:

```
 (b=3, a=5)
```

You then return:

```
 (b-a) or (3-5)
```

which is -2.

Answer (score 0):

The actual names of the parameters in the function don't matter. You're getting confused because wherever you found the example- they cleverly reversed the order of `b` and `a`. However the names in the parameter are just used in the function scope and don't affect variables of the same name outside of it. For example:

```
var a = 3;
var b = 5;
example(a, b);

function example(bacon, eggs) {
  var result = bacon - eggs;
  alert(result);
}
```

Would also return `-2` because the first parameter we pass through to example is `a` (3) and the second is `b` (5) and `3-5 = -2`. Doesn't matter what the name of the parameters in example actually are named- its important to keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code. The problem is with your lecture of the code. The result is in fact, -2. Debug your code in Chrome Debugger or similar

```js
var a = 3; // a equals 3
var b = 5; // b equals 5
example(a, b); // Replacing variables this is the same as example(3,5)      
      
// Changing variables names so you don't get mixed up
function example(c, d) { 
   // Since you called example(3,5) then c = 3 and d = 5
   var result = c - d; // This results in -2
   alert(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't be confused with the variable names because in js, it works by the **order** of your function argument not by variable name of functions. To get what you want as output i.e **2**, try like this.

```js
example(b = 5, a = 3);

function example(b, a) {
  var result = b - a;
  alert(result);
}
```

[image]

If you've any confusion go to http://www.pythontutor.com/javascript.html and see what is happening under the hood.